# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userTokenService'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

> `homeControler`

```
    package com.book.controller;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.entity.security.UserToken;
import com.book.entity.security.service.SecurityService;
import com.book.entity.security.service.UserTokenService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserTokenService userTokenService;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHome() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/myaccount")
    public String myAccount() {
        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveLogin", true);
        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forgetPassword")
    public String forgetPassword(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveForgetPassword", true);
        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/newUser")
    public String newUser(Locale locale, @RequestParam("token") String token, Model model) {

        UserToken userToken = userTokenService.getPasswordResetToken(token);
        if (userToken == null) {
            String msg = "Invalid Token";
            model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
            return "redirect:/badRequest";
        }

        User user = userToken.getUser();
        String username = user.getUsername();

        UserDetails userDetails = securityService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(),
                userDetails.getAuthorities());

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        model.addAttribute("classActiveEdit", true);
        return "myProfile";
    }
}
```

> User Token

```
package com.book.entity.security;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import com.book.entity.User;

@Entity
public class UserToken {

    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String token;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_id")
    private User user;

    private Date expiryDate;

    public UserToken(final String token, final User user) {
        super ();

        this.token = token;
        this.user = user;
        this.expiryDate = calculateExpiryDate(EXPIRATION);
    }

    private Date calculateExpiryDate (final int expiryTimeInMinutes) {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, expiryTimeInMinutes);
        return new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }

    public void updateToken(final String token) {
        this.token = token;
        this.expiryDate = calculateExpiryDate(EXPIRATION);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "P_Token [id=" + id + ", token=" + token + ", user=" + user + ", expiryDate=" + expiryDate + "]";
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public static int getExpiration() {
        return EXPIRATION;
    }



}
```

> UserTokenService

```
package com.book.entity.security.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.entity.security.UserToken;
import com.book.entity.security.repo.PasswordResetRepo;
import com.book.entity.security.repo.UserTokenRepo;

@Service("userTokenService")
public class UserTokenService implements UserTokenRepo{

    @Autowired
    private PasswordResetRepo repo;

    @Override
    public UserToken getPasswordResetToken(final String token) {
        return repo.findByToken(token);
    }

    @Override
    public void createPasswordResetTokenForUser(final User user, final String token) {
        final UserToken myToken = new UserToken(token, user);
        repo.save(myToken);
    }
}
```

> UserTokenRepo

```
package com.book.entity.security.repo;

import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.entity.security.UserToken;

public interface UserTokenRepo {

    UserToken getPasswordResetToken(final String token);

    void createPasswordResetTokenForUser(final User user, final String token);

}
```

> SecurityService

```
package com.book.entity.security.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.entity.security.repo.SecurityUserRepository;

@Service
public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserRepository securityUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = securityUserRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (null == user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

> PasswordResetRepo

```
package com.book.entity.security.repo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.entity.security.UserToken;


public interface PasswordResetRepo extends JpaRepository<UserToken, Long > {

    UserToken findByToken(String token);

    UserToken findByUser(User user);

    Stream<UserToken> findAllByExpiryDateLessThan(Date now);

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from P_Token t where t.expirydate <= ?1")
    void deleteAllExpiredSince(Date now);
}
```

Error:-->
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userTokenService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userTokenService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordResetRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException

Comment: Can you provide the code for PasswordResetRepo? Is it marked as component?

Comment: its an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be problem lays on `HomeController` bellow code:

```
@Autowired
    private UserTokenService userTokenService;
```

Replace this code with bellow code:

```
@Autowired
        private UserTokenRepo userTokenService;
```

Your main error portion is:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'passwordResetRepo': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   antlr/RecognitionException

Here it is failed to create bean `passwordResetRepo` cause `antlr/RecognitionException`

Its solution is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException shows **antlr lib missing**.

Add it and itss done :)

You can try to add the following dependency. It will solve your issue.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Another possible consideration:**

Please check all JPA query on `PasswordResetRepo` repository. Sometimes if query not matched with entity variable name then Spring can't create bean for that repository

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the stacktrace. The issue is: spring IoC container is failing to create `homeController` bean; because the container is failing to create `userTokenService` bean; and that is because the container is failing to create `passwordResetRepo` bean with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Adding the following in your config file should solve your problem:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.book.entity.security.repo" />
```

As you are using Spring Boot, please check this guide on [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

From the above mentioned guide:

> By default, Spring Boot will enable `JPA` repository support and look
>   in the package (and its subpackages) where `@SpringBootApplication` is
>   located. If your configuration has `JPA` repository interface
>   definitions located in a package not visible, you can point out
>   alternate packages using `@EnableJpaRepositories` and its type-safe
>   `basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class` parameter.

Comment: sir, but i am using spring Boot and i am fully new in spring ...please give me valuable suggestions. thanks a lot sir. please tell me what is the confg file in my project?

Comment: @JahadulRakib, I have updated the answer according to your comment. Please take a look.

Comment: thanks a lot sir...i request u in fb when i see you stay in Dhaka.